# Expected unqualified-id before string constant in header file dealing with extern "C"

Tags: c++, pspsdk

I am developing a PSP game and the compiler is complaing about extern "C" in a header file, which I do not see anything wrong with the header file.

Exact message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PSP Pong, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  psp-g++ -I. -Ic:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include -O2 -G0 -Wall  -I. -Ic:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include -O2 -G0 -Wall  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -D_PSP_FW_VERSION=150   -c -o main.o main.cpp
1>  In file included from c:/pspsdk/psp/sdk/include/JRenderer.h (19) ,
1>                   from main.cpp (10) :
1>c:/pspsdk/lib/gcc/../../psp/include/gif_lib.h(20): error : expected unqualified-id before string constant
1>  c:\pspsdk\bin\make: *** [main.o] Error 1
1>  Press any key to continue . . . 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error MSB3073: The command "c:\pspsdk\bin\vsmake.bat" exited with code -1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

JRenderer.h

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//
// JGE++ is a hardware accelerated 2D game SDK for PSP/Windows.
//
// Licensed under the BSD license, see LICENSE in JGE root for details.
// 
// Copyright (c) 2007 James Hui (a.k.a. Dr.Watson) <jhkhui@gmail.com>
// 
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef _JRENDERER_H_
#define _JRENDERER_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include <gif_lib.h>

#include "JTypes.h"


#ifdef WIN32

    #include <windows.h>

#else

    #include <pspgu.h>
    #include <pspkernel.h>
    #include <pspdisplay.h>
    #include <pspdebug.h> 
    #include <pspctrl.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <pspaudiolib.h>
    #include <psprtc.h>

#endif


#include "Vector2D.h"

#define USING_MATH_TABLE

#ifdef USING_MATCH_TABLE
    #define SINF(x)     mSinTable[x]
    #define COSF(x)     mCosTable[x]
#else
    #define SINF(x)     sinf(x*DEG2RAD)
    #define COSF(x)     cosf(x*DEG2RAD)
#endif


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// A collection of core rendering functions. 
///
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class JRenderer
{
protected:

    JRenderer();
    ~JRenderer();
    void InitRenderer();
    void DestroyRenderer();



public:

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Get the singleton instance
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    static JRenderer* GetInstance();

    static void Destroy();

    static void Set3DFlag(bool flag);

    void BeginScene();
    void EndScene();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Render a textured quad with rotation and scaling.
    ///
    /// @param quad - Quad with texturing info.
    /// @param xo - x position.
    /// @param yo - y position.
    /// @param angle - Rotation (radian).
    /// @param xScale - Horizontal rendering scale.
    /// @param yScale - Vertical rendering scale.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void RenderQuad(JQuad* quad, float xo, float yo, float angle=0.0f, float xScale=1.0f, float yScale=1.0f);


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Render a textured quad with new texture mapping information.
    ///
    /// @param quad - Quad with texturing information.
    /// @param points - Array of vertices with new texture mapping information.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void RenderQuad(JQuad* quad, VertexColor* points);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Taking a screen shot.
    /// 
    /// @note This function works on PSP only. A PNG file will be saved in 
    /// the current folder of the game applicaton.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void ScreenShot(const char* filename);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Load a texture from file.
    /// 
    /// @param filename - Name of file.
    /// @param mode - Choose to put texture in VRAM (PSP only).
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    JTexture* LoadTexture(const char* filename, int mode = 0);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Create texture from memory on the fly.
    /// 
    /// @param width - Width of texture.
    /// @param height - Height of texture.
    /// @param mode - Choose to put texture in VRAM (PSP only)
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    JTexture* CreateTexture(int width, int height, int mode = 0);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Clear entire screen to a particular color.
    /// 
    /// @param color - Color to fill the screen.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void ClearScreen(PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Enable VSync for the smoothness of moving objects. (PSP only)
    /// 
    /// @param flag - true to enable, false to disable.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void EnableVSync(bool flag);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Enable bi-linear filtering for better looking on-screen images.
    /// 
    /// @param flag - true to enable, false to disable.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void EnableTextureFilter(bool flag);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Remove all textures from VRAM (PSP only)
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void ResetPrivateVRAM();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Enable/disable swizzle optimization. (PSP only)
    /// 
    /// @param s - 1 to enable, 0 to disable.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void SetSwizzle(int s) { mSwizzle = s; }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Bind texture to be used for the rendering followed.
    /// 
    /// @param tex - Texture to use.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void BindTexture(JTexture *tex);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Set texture blending options.
    /// 
    /// @par Blending options:
    ///
    /// @code
    ///
    ///     BLEND_ZERO
    ///     BLEND_ONE
    ///     BLEND_SRC_COLOR
    ///     BLEND_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR
    ///     BLEND_SRC_ALPHA
    ///     BLEND_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
    ///     BLEND_DST_ALPHA 
    ///     BLEND_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA
    ///     BLEND_DST_COLOR 
    ///     BLEND_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR
    ///     BLEND_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE
    ///
    /// @endcode
    ///
    /// @param src - Blending option for source image.
    /// @param dest - Blending option for destination image.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void SetTexBlend(int src, int dest);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Set texture blending option for source image.
    /// 
    /// @param src - Blending option for source image.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void SetTexBlendSrc(int src);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Set texture blending option for destination image.
    /// 
    /// @param dest - Blending option for destination image.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void SetTexBlendDest(int dest);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Enable rendering in 2D mode.
    /// 
    /// @note To be implemented.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void Enable2D();


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Enable rendering in 3D mode.
    ///
    /// @note To be implemented.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void Enable3D();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Restrict all rendering to a rectangular area.
    ///
    /// @note This is just the glScissor() function of OpenGL.
    /// 
    /// @param x - Left of the clipping area.
    /// @param y - Top of the clipping area.
    /// @param width - Width of the clipping area.
    /// @param height - Height of the clipping area.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void SetClip(int x, int y, int width, int height);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Reset Modelview Identity.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void LoadIdentity();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Tranlate position in 3D space.
    ///
    /// @param x - X position.
    /// @param y - Y position.
    /// @param z - Z position.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void Translate(float x, float y, float z);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Rotate along X axis.
    /// 
    /// @param angle - Angle to rotate ( in radians).
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void RotateX(float angle);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Rotate along Y axis.
    /// 
    /// @param angle - Angle to rotate ( in radians).
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void RotateY(float angle);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Rotate along Z axis.
    /// 
    /// @param angle - Angle to rotate ( in radians).
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void RotateZ(float angle);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Push matrix.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void PushMatrix();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Pop matrix.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void PopMatrix();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Set the field of view angle (in degrees), effective at the next
    /// Enable3D() call.
    /// 
    /// @param fov - The field of view angle (in degrees).
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void SetFOV(float fov);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Render triangles.
    /// 
    /// @param texture - Texture for the triangles.
    /// @param tris - List of triangles.
    /// @param start - starting index (Note: Index of triangles, NOT vertices).
    /// @param count - Number of triangles (Note: NOT number of vertices).
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void RenderTriangles(JTexture* texture, Vertex3D *tris, int start, int count);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Fill a rectangular area with a specified color.
    ///
    /// @param x - Starting x position.
    /// @param y - Starting y position.
    /// @param width - Width of the rectangle.
    /// @param height - Height of the rectangle.
    /// @param color - Filling color.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void FillRect(float x, float y, float width, float height, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Fill a rectangular area with a single color for each vertex.
    ///
    /// @param x - Starting x position.
    /// @param y - Starting y position.
    /// @param width - Width of the rectangle.
    /// @param height - Height of the rectangle.
    /// @param color - Array of colors.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void FillRect(float x, float y, float width, float height, JColor* color);
    void FillRect(float x, float y, float width, float height, PIXEL_TYPE* color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw a rectangle.
    ///
    /// @param x - Starting x position.
    /// @param y - Starting y position.
    /// @param width - Width of the rectangle.
    /// @param height - Height of the rectangle.
    /// @param color - Filling color.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void DrawRect(float x, float y, float width, float height, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw a single line.
    ///
    /// @param x1 - Starting vertex, x.
    /// @param y1 - Starting vertex, y.
    /// @param x2 - Ending vertex, x.
    /// @param y2 - Ending vertex, y.
    /// @param color - Filling color.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void DrawLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw thick line.
    ///
    /// @param x1 - Starting vertex, x.
    /// @param y1 - Starting vertex, y.
    /// @param x2 - Ending vertex, x.
    /// @param y2 - Ending vertex, y.
    /// @param lineWidth - Line width.
    /// @param color - Filling color.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void DrawLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float lineWidth, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Plot a pixel on screen.
    /// 
    /// @param x - X position of the pixel.
    /// @param y - Y position of the pixel.
    /// @param color - Draw colour.
    /// 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void Plot(float x, float y, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Plot an array of pixels.
    /// 
    /// @param x - Array of X positions.
    /// @param y - Array of Y positions.
    /// @param count - Number of pixels to plot.
    /// @param color - Color of pixel.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void PlotArray(float *x, float *y, int count, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw polygon with filled colour.
    /// 
    /// @param x - Array of X positions.
    /// @param y - Array of Y positions.
    /// @param count - Side count of the polygon.
    /// @param color - Filling colour.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void FillPolygon(float* x, float* y, int count, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw polygon.
    /// 
    /// @param x - Array of X positions.
    /// @param y - Array of Y positions.
    /// @param count - Side count of the polygon.
    /// @param color - Draw colour.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void DrawPolygon(float* x, float* y, int count, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw symmetric polygon with certain number of sides.
    /// 
    /// @param x - X positions of center of the polygon.
    /// @param y - Y positions of center of the polygon.
    /// @param size - Size of polygon.
    /// @param count - Side count of the polygon.
    /// @param startingAngle - Rotation angle of the polygon.
    /// @param color - Draw colour.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void DrawPolygon(float x, float y, float size, int count, float startingAngle, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw solid symmetric polygon with certain number of sides.
    /// 
    /// @param x - X positions of center of the polygon.
    /// @param y - Y positions of center of the polygon.
    /// @param size - Size of polygon.
    /// @param count - Side count of the polygon.
    /// @param startingAngle - Rotation angle of the polygon.
    /// @param color - Filling colour.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void FillPolygon(float x, float y, float size, int count, float startingAngle, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw circle with filled colour.
    /// 
    /// @param x - X positions of center of the circle.
    /// @param y - Y positions of center of the circle.
    /// @param radius - Radius of circle.
    /// @param color - Filling colour.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void FillCircle(float x, float y, float radius, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw circle.
    /// 
    /// @param x - X positions of center of the circle.
    /// @param y - Y positions of center of the circle.
    /// @param radius - Radius of circle.
    /// @param color - Draw colour.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void DrawCircle(float x, float y, float radius, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw a rectangle with round corners.
    ///
    /// @param x - Starting x position.
    /// @param y - Starting y position.
    /// @param w - Width of the rectangle.
    /// @param h - Height of the rectangle.
    /// @param radius - Radius of the round corners.
    /// @param color - Drawing color.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void DrawRoundRect(float x, float y, float w, float h, float radius, PIXEL_TYPE color);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Draw filled rectangle with round corners.
    ///
    /// @param x - Starting x position.
    /// @param y - Starting y position.
    /// @param w - Width of the rectangle.
    /// @param h - Height of the rectangle.
    /// @param radius - Radius of the round corners.
    /// @param color - Filling color.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void FillRoundRect(float x, float y, float w, float h, float radius, PIXEL_TYPE color);


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Set custom image filter to be used at texture loading.
    ///
    /// @param imageFilter - Custom image filter.
    ///
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    void SetImageFilter(JImageFilter* imageFilter);

private:

    struct TextureInfo
    {
        u8 *mBits;
        int mWidth;
        int mHeight;
        int mTexWidth;
        int mTexHeight;
        bool mVRAM;
    };

    void LoadJPG(TextureInfo &textureInfo, const char *filename, int mode = 0);
    void LoadPNG(TextureInfo &textureInfo, const char *filename, int mode = 0);
    void LoadGIF(TextureInfo &textureInfo, const char *filename, int mode = 0);
    int image_readgif(void * handle, TextureInfo &textureInfo, DWORD * bgcolor, InputFunc readFunc,int mode = 0);

    static JRenderer* mInstance;


#ifdef WIN32

    GLuint mCurrentTex;


#else

    u32 mVideoBufferStart;
    //u32 mCurrentPointer;
    PIXEL_TYPE* mVRAM;
    int mCurrentTex;
    int mCurrentBlend;

#endif

    bool mVsync;

    int mSwizzle;
    int mTexCounter;

    //int mTexFilter;

    int mCurrentTextureFilter;

    int mCurrTexBlendSrc;
    int mCurrTexBlendDest;

    JImageFilter* mImageFilter;

    int mCurrentRenderMode;

    float mFOV;

#ifdef USING_MATH_TABLE
    float mSinTable[360];
    float mCosTable[360];
#endif

    static bool m3DEnabled;
};


#endif
```

Comment: can you post the portion of JRenderer.h that includes gif_lib.h?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the header either -- at least nothing that would cause the error you're seeing.  I suspect there's an error in the file that includes it, directly or indirectly.  What does your `main.cpp` look like?  Is there anything odd before the `#include` directive?

Comment: This error is usally due to the extern "C" being in a place where "C" code is not allowed, like inside a class definition or implementation.

Comment: it is likely somewhere in a header you include before those...usually a syntax error in a prior include will cause this. A missing semicolon after class declaration or something like that can be the culprit...what do you include before the render header?

Comment: @Jim Rhodes Well actually I am not sure which header file is including that gif_lib.h. I am assuming its JRenderer.h but I am not sure.

Comment: The error message says it's `JRenderer.h`. BTW, I recommend using the `-E` option of `g++` to get a preprocessed file, and check what is wrong.

Comment: This actually sounds like `__cplusplus` is defined even though it's compiling in C mode. That would explain why it gets into that `#ifdef` clause and also why it doesn't recognize the `extern "C"` construct.

Comment: I've seen a message very similar to that when a C compiler was asked to process `extern "C" ...`; the fix is to make sure that the header does not insist on C++ and detects when C++ is not in use.

Comment: I agree with Keith, Jim, Jyore. Probably a missing } or ; in the file that #include the gif_lib.h. Line 20 is the extern "C" { ... } which is valid C++ as you'd expect.

Comment: I ran to this problem today and @Jom Rhodes is actually correct. Thanks a lot!